# Joining datasets in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have two datasets in SSRS.  I'd like to join them in a single report.

The first is a list of products with productnumber as the key and a builddate.

```
productnumber builddate
123           6/1/2005 
123           6/1/2015
```

The second is a secondary identifier that has an effectively date.

The table looks like this:

```
productnumber secondarynumber effectivedate obsoletedate
123           999             1/1/2000      12/31/2009
123           999A            1/1/2010      1/1/2030
```

I'd like the report to look like this:

```
productnumber builddate secondarynumber
123           6/1/2005  999
123           6/1/2015  999A
```

Is this possible?  I tried using Lookup and LookupSet to return the secondarynumber but I'm at a loss for how to pass the filter params in or how to use a record set output.  I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you tried this `=Lookup(Fields!productnumber.Value,Fields!productnumber.Value,Fields!secondarynumber.Value,"Table2DataSet")`?

Comment: The return of the secondarynumber is dependent on the builddate which isn't included in your lookup.  If I use LookupSet I get two records, one for each builddate. At that point I only have the secondarynumbers, I don't have the builddate.

Comment: Lookup returns the first value found, so in your case it will return `999` as `secondarynumber` for both rows. How do you relate builddate in the second dataset to get the corresponding secondarynumber?

Comment: Lol...  that's what I'm asking :-)

Comment: If you had included in your question that you need the row which builddate is between effective and obsolete dates, it had been more clear. Also it is not easy to guess it if one of your dates is 6/1/ **1015** , is it even a valid date?

Comment: My error.  I figured it could be gleaned from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**T-SQL Solution** (Easiest if your datasource is a database and you are not restricted to use unmodifiable stored procedures)

If your datasource is a database you can handle it easily from a T-SQL query, by performing a JOIN between both tables and specify a WHERE clause to select only the rows matching the condition: effectivedate <= buildDate =< obsoletedate.

```
SELECT a.Productnumber, 
       a.Builddate, 
       b.Secondarynumber 
FROM   Dataset1table a 
       INNER JOIN Dataset2table b 
               ON a.Productnumber = b.Productnumber 
WHERE  a.Builddate BETWEEN b.Effectivedate AND b.Obsoletedate
```

**SSRS Solution:**

Go to `Report` menu / `Report properties...` under the Code tab add the following VB function.

```
Public Function GetSecondaryNumber(buildDate As Date ,
effectiveDate As Object, obsoleteDate As Object, secondaryNumber As Object) As String

Dim i As Integer    

For i = 0  To effectiveDate.Length -1 
  if buildDate >= effectiveDate(i) and buildDate <= obsoleteDate(i) then
     Return secondaryNumber(i)
   End If
Next 

Return ""

End Function
```

Then in the `secondarynumber` column in your tablix use:

```
=Code.GetSecondaryNumber(
Fields!builddate.Value,
LookupSet(Fields!productnumber.Value,Fields!productnumber.Value,Fields!effectivedate.Value,"DataSet2"),
LookupSet(Fields!productnumber.Value,Fields!productnumber.Value,Fields!obsoletedate.Value,"DataSet2"),
LookupSet(Fields!productnumber.Value,Fields!productnumber.Value,Fields!secondarynumber.Value,"DataSet2")
)
```

> It will work if you don't have Nulls in effectiveDate and
>   obsoleteDate columns. Otherwise you will have to handle null
>   validation in the VB function or SSRS.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I guess this is only way for OP solution. Nicely explained.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I think I can do the SSRS solution and it seems like it will work.  (I'll try tomorrow.)  Another detail I should have put in the question is the datasets are coming from two different databases.  (DB2/Not linked.)  Is the T-SQL possible in this case?

Comment: @tzerb, if each database is in a different server and you can [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx#Anchor_2) both servers the T-SQL solution could help you. Otherwise implement the SSRS solution.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta can't link them and the SSRS solution works if a little verbose.  Thanks for all the help.